# execute sql task error

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012, ssis-2008

An execute sql task has been defined as below.the parameter mapping is
system:Username  input varchar 0 -1
System:packagename  input varchar 1 -1

```
DECLARE @DataLoaderUsername VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @PackageName VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @Code VARCHAR(5)
DECLARE @RunNumber INT

SET @DataLoaderUsername = ?
SET @PackageName = ?
SET @Code = 'bbb'


INSERT INTO tBL_Log
(LoadDateTime,DataLoaderUsername,PackageName,Code)
SELECT GetDate(),@DataLoaderUsername,@PackageName ,@Code

SELECT @RunNumber = Max(RunNumber) 
FROM tBL_Log

SELECT @RunNumber As LoadID
```

It shows an error

```
Execute SQL Task] Error: Executing the query "DECLARE @DataLoaderUsername VARCHAR(100)
```

The same query executed in ssms and it works fine(with a hardcoded username)

Answer (score 1):

Put semi-colons at the end of each SQL command.  When SSIS sends the command to SQL Server, it sends it as a single line, so semi-colons are needed to show SQL Server where each new command begins.

Comment: There should be more to the error message.   Can you post the entire message?

Answer (score 0):

Your code inside the Execute SQL Task should only contain the following.

```
INSERT INTO tBL_Log
(LoadDateTime,DataLoaderUsername,PackageName,Code)
SELECT GetDate(),? ,?, 'bbb'

SELECT LoadID = Max(RunNumber) 
FROM tBL_Log
```

In the General page, make sure you have `ResultSet` set to single row, and the DB connection also set to a valid connection manager.

[image]

I think you've already setup your `Parameters` page, just make sure they look like the following. Remember the index for the parameters starts at `0` and is specified in the `Parameter Name` box (Not intuitive, I know. It tripped me up in the beginning when I was learning SSIS).

[image]

Finally, in order to get the `LoadId` value that you are selecting in the last statement, create a variable to hold that value in the **ResultSet** pane. The **ResultSet** should be called `0`.

[image]

So it looks like this.

[image]